# Overriding trouble

Tags: java, methods, overriding

My code looks sort of like this, but this is a simplified version:

class A:

```
public class A{
    public void testArgs(A a){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

class B:

```
public class B extends A{
    public void testArgs(B a){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

class Main:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        a(new B()).testArgs(new B()); // prints A
        (new B()).testArgs(new B());  // prints B
        a(new B()).test();            // prints B
    }
    public static A a(B b){
        return b;
    }
}
```

Why does `a(new B()).testArgs(new B())` print A not B?
Is there some sort of way to workaround/fix this?

edit:
Clarification:

What I really want is the superclass method to be run when it is called with an A, and the subclass method to be run when testArgs is called with a B.

Casting also isn't an option because in the actual code, unlike here, I don't know whether the result of the method call is actually B or not.

edit:
Solution:

Thanks everyone for your answers. Thanks for the clarification on overriding. I used this to implement the desired behavior.
For anyone who has a similar problem in the future:
Change class B to

```
public class B extends A{
    public void testArgs(A a){       // Corrected overriding, thanks
        if(a instanceof B)           // Check if it is an instance of B
            System.out.println("B"); // Do whatever
        else                         // Otherwise
            super.testArgs(a);       // Call superclass method
    }
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two `testArgs` functions are different.  One takes an `A` and the other takes a `B`.  Thus, the `B` version doesnt override the `A` version.  Since `a(new B())` is of type `A` and `B` extends `A`, it is the `A` version that will run.

There is a "workaround":

```
public class B extends A{
public void testArgs(A a){ // <-- note how this is A a, not B a 
    System.out.println("B");
}
public void test(){
    System.out.println("B");
}
}
```

Then you will see `B` for all 3 cases (because `B`'s `testArgs` will override `A`'s `testArgs`)

Comment: That's not called overloading.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How would I make it so that the super class method runs when testargs is called with is called with an A, but the subclass method runs when testargs is called with a B?

Comment: This highlights the usefulness of using `@Override` on methods that you intend on being overrides.  If `@Override` has been used on B's testArgs() method, the compiler would have flagged it as an error, making it obvious something is wrong.

Comment: @prunge when was \@Override introduced?

Comment: @FooBah: 1.5 for overriding methods; 1.6 for implementing methods

Answer (score 1):

The call `a(new B())` returns a new `B` instance of type `A`, when invoking `testArgs()` it gets called in class `A` and prints `"A"`. Correct.

Should the method `testArgs()` override the one in super class, then the sub class version will get invoked, by means of polymorphism (but its not your case).

So to get your expected result, class `B` needs to properly override the method in super:

```
public class B extends A{
public void testArgs(A a){ // polymorphism would work 
   System.out.println("B");
} 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Debugging the problem at run-time is rather difficult. There's a very simple way to let the compiler warn you by using the anotation @Overrides

public class B extends A{

```
@Overrides
public void testArgs(B a){
    System.out.println("B");
}

@Overrides
public void test(){
    System.out.println("B");
}
```

}

If I have inadvertently left out a parameter or used a wrong one then @Overrides will catch my error at compile time itself.

Answer (score -2):

In your first statement, that prints "A", you could workaround the issue by casting the result of the static `a()` call to a `B`:

```
((B) a(new B())).testArgs(new B());
```